# Seeking algorithm to find point on surface with highest visibility?

Tags: algorithm, viewshed, visibility

I have a DEM which I want to find a point with largest amount of visibility ,I know that viewshed leads to visibility from a point but how can I find a point with highest visibility ?

One way is to loop every pixel in my DEM and then calculate visibility for each pixel. but this is not a very clever method.

Is there any tools or Algorithms which I can use to achieve this goal?

I can use c++ to run the algorithm.

Comment: You can limit search to local maximumss

Comment: @FelixIP But not all maximums are the points with highest amount of visibility

Comment: Correct, but it will greatly reduce list of candidates.

Comment: @FelixIP humm, I had this in my mind but How can I find local windows size to search?

Comment: I'd start with very large and compare with something much smaller. I don't think you'll find much difference. Yes, a lot of iterations..

Comment: @FelixIP huum what if we select pixels which are more than a=((max_elevation-min_elevation)/2) and calculate visibility for them then again calculate it for pixels with hight more than b=((max_elevation-a)/2)  if a<b then continue again for c=((max_elevation-b)/2) and if a>b continue with c=((a-min_elevation)/2) to find the exact pixel?which ones performance is better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65518/discussion-between-felixip-and-majid-hojati).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whitebox GAT software has a tool that does what you need to do (I think), its called Visibility Index. From the manual:

*This tool can be used to calculate the visibility of all locations within an input digital elevation model (DEM)*

Whitebox is an opensource tool so there is an option for viewing the underlying code. You should be able to work out from there how it works.

You can download Whitebox for free here: http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/

Comment: thanks very much for your help, I'll take a look at it and hope I can find some informations about the algorithm behind it

Comment: The developer of whitebox (Dr John Lindsay) is on here as WhiteBoxDev. He might be able to assist https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35151/whiteboxdev

Comment: Thanks very much, It is exactly what I need but it simply loops over every pixel I want to find an optimized method, I'll ask Dr. Lindsay to find out more about it

Comment: Something that might spark some thoughts (this may not work and I haven't tested). Would a looping of that tool using a lower resolution than your DEM grid find areas of generally higher resolution that you could then feed into a more detailed analysis using those areas as locations? It would avoid looping repeatedly over redundant areas of a high resolution DEM.

Comment: So you mean we can some how divide area into bigger pixels and then select those area and test on real image?

Comment: Sort of. The whitebox tool allows you to set a resolution factor (n) and says "If a value of n is used, the viewshed will be calculated for every nth column and row, greatly decreasing the amount of processing necessary" - perhaps you could look at using a high value of n to narrow down the areas that you would need to run a high resolution visibility index on? You could run it as some kind of iteration. I don't know how you would do this by Dr Lindsay might be able to help.